# Is it possible to generate a T4 template (.tt) based on an existing class?

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I've written some classes and would like to create a T4 template (with some variables).
Is it possible to generate a T4 template based on an existing class?

e.g.

```
public class ClassA
{
    private const string MyField = "Test-A";

    public ClassA()
    {

    }
}
```

In this case I would like to have a (auto generated) T4 template of this class.
Afterwards, the 'A' character will be modified as a variable within the template.
So basically, the T4 will be able to generate a ClassB, ClassC, ClassD.

This example is using a really simple implementation, but I need a T4 based on a more complex class, so I would rather generate one, instead of manually create a whole new one.

Comment: So you want to generate a new T4 template, using a T4 template that reads .cs files?

Comment: @TimMaes That is indeed what I am trying to achieve!

Comment: Since a T4 template is basically one big stringbuilder under the hood, this is perfectly achievable, but I think it will be very complex to generate 1 generic template for this. This tutorial might help you kickstart https://tim-maes.com/2019/03/28/t4-beginner-tutorial/ . Instead of reading from text, you can read from .cs file (or even use reflection to find types etc) and generate a new .tt file instead of .cs files